# Can't find Android phone in Devices

Tags: android

I have already Googled this problem a thousand times over; and I've tried every 'fix' to no avail.

Using 'adb devices' via command line produces an empty list.. The phone is plugged in (this is the phone http://www.bestbuy.com/site/lg-g2-4g-lte-with-32gb-memory-cell-phone-black-verizon-wireless/1723195.p?id=1219061252155&).

Nothing shows up when I try to run my application from Android Dev studio.

I have the Google USB drivers installed; but my computer (running Windows 8.1) always wants to use an MTP USB Device (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1TBL.png)

The phone, in Device Manager, is listed under 'Portable Devices' instead of other... (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ1um.png)

I have tried manually entering the ID of the phone. I'm honestly just at a loss.. I've tried PTP mode. Everything! I've tried using different (micro-usb) cables... Dev mode is enabled on phone.

Please, any help would be great... Thanks.

EDIT: I found an older Android phone I used to use and used that instead of the LG G2.. it worked instantly. I will use that for testing purposes. Thanks for all who commented!

Comment: install "PdaNet" thn try again

Comment: Which device you have?

Comment: I seem to have the LG G2. It isn't my phone.. Rather my clients. I will ask them to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in Developer Options USB debugging is enable then try [this](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/manualinstall.php).
If this will not detect the device then download download driver from LG website, if this also not work then download general ADB usb driver which is available on lot's of website.

Comment: I should've added it (and I'll edit it in) but Developer Options is enabled on the phone. I will try your link..Thanks!

Comment: That didn't seem to work... I have already tried manually installing the driver via Device Manager; but my computer automatically assigns a driver to it and then doesn't allow me to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings", then "About Phone". Tap on the build number 7 times to enable developer mode. Go to the developer options and absolutely make sure USB debugging is on (sometimes it unchecks itself and you have to go back in and turn it on again). Vinit is correct, you need the USB driver for the computer for the phone to even show up on the list.

Comment: It's all enabled.. has been for awhile. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: @user3400029 Then the issue must be the drivers. Who is the manufacturer of your computer? The driver will be on that website. I can find it for you or you can find it if you know where to find it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I built my computer myself...

I have an MSI motherboard, AMD quad core processor, ATI Radeon Saphire graphics card, and 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: @user3400029 I went to AMD's website and they do offer support drivers. Just go to the AMD website and search for the USB driver.

Answer (score 0):

LG Gx model phones have issues with ADB. I ran into similar issues with the G3. At least with the G3 there were several USB connection options:

MTP, PTP, Ethernet, and Power Only

With the G3 I had success after installing the drivers from LG directly and then switching from MTP to Ethernet (internet version of ethernet) after plugging it in. For some reason unknown to me, the phone showed up in ADB with that option selected, but did not show up in Windows Explorer.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: If I select internet connection then my phone doesn't show up as a portable device; rather in 'Other'. However, when I try to manually assign it a driver it says Windows could not find a driver for it. 

I've tried using both the Google USB drivers and the LG G2 (Universal) drivers.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was hoping it would work as that is what I did with the G3

Comment: Yes, it seems to be rather difficult. I found an old Android phone I used to use; so I will give that a shot instead of the LG G2.